# validate repeated radio buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form using the jquery validate plugin.
i managed to make it work with array of inputs.
for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-holder">
        <input class="text" name="childFirstName[]" type="text" />
        <label>שם הילד/ה:</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

lets say i have un known number of inputs so i must use this method.

i managed to make the plugin to check all the inputs.
also i have 2 radio buttons.

```
<div class="row row-alt">
    <div class="row-holder">
        <div class="col-checkbox">
            <label>נקבה</label>
            <input class="radio" value="1" name="childGender[]" type="radio" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-checkbox">
            <label>זכר</label>
            <input class="radio" value="0" name="childGender[]" type="radio" />
        </div>
        <strong>מין:</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

and as you might guess. they are both within the same block.
so when i duplicate it and make lots of it... they first act like the one (if i choose 1 it affects all the radios in the form)
also the validator don't seem to validate it.

here is a link:
http://jwtdigital.co.il/MyMaterna/form.php

hope you can help me with this.
sorry for my terrible english :-)

Comment: do you want multiple radios to be checked ?

Comment: I want to be able to add infinite number of blocks with fields. in every block i need 2 radio of gender buttons.

now, if ill check male - ALL the checkbox will become unchecked and it will check the one i pressed on - removing the others.

every block should be independent.

Comment: you need to change the name of each group

Comment: but then i won't be able to know what is the name of each gender field on the server side.

Comment: save the number of groups in hidden input and increment it by JS and give a postfix for each group for example childGender1[] and childGender2[] and you can get the number on the server from the hidden input and loop to it

Comment: its an idea - but i can't change the server side. i am not authorized to do this

Comment: Then it will be a very long story with JS

Comment: If you want help with the jQuery Validate plugin, then show your code that includes `.validate()`.  Please don't expect us to dig through your website.  Otherwise, it's tedious and some day soon the question will become useless to future readers.

Comment: Also, create a concise demo of your form using english only.

Comment: Now the link to your demo page is dead because of PHP errors... this is another reason why a link to a live page should not be used as a demo. Voting to close this question until you can post _the code_ of a complete and concise example into your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code...

```
<input class="radio" value="1" name="childGender[]" type="radio" />
<input class="radio" value="0" name="childGender[]" type="radio" />
```

I cannot be certain because you have not posted enough code and your demo page link is now dead, but perhaps you've neglected to properly handle the special characters within your `radio` `name`.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29

Names containing brackets, `[]` **must** be enclosed in quotes when the `rules` are declared within `.validate()`...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            //other rules,
            'childGender[]': {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/RNHDy/**